# A property of complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

It is simple one. In my school book it says
[image]

is there any mistake here? Because i think otherwise.

btw question is showing $ \int_{γ}(c_1f+c_2g)=c_1\int_{γ}f+c_2\int_{γ}g$

Comment: Yes, clearly these are mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just at a superficial glance, I see you (if the pencil is you) made a good correction.  The reason for this is that

$$(u+i v) (x' + i y') = (u x' - v y') + i (v x' + u y') $$

The term $(u x'+v y')$ makes no sense, and is the result of a clear error.